# Share on Social Media Platforms in Angular application

Tags: facebook, angular, twitter, whatsapp, socialshare

Is there any component that allows content sharing on WhatsApp from angular2 application?

I found the `ng2-social-share` module but it doesn't support WhatsApp, documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-social-share).

Another documentation on git that supports way more platforms but not WhatsApp. Link is [here](https://github.com/cedvdb/ng2share).

Is there any component available that supports Facebook, email, WhatsApp and Twitter all? Please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no good Component for JavaScript. Whatsapp doesn't provide an open API. Maybe there are some third-party APIs but Whatsapp does not officially support this services and maybe it's not legal to use them.

Comment: and which component should i use for facebook and twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the third party sharing plugins like ***[AddToAny](https://www.addtoany.com/)***. It offers sharing over enough amount of social platforms. Here are more for your ref. - [shareThis](https://www.sharethis.com/), [addThis](http://www.addthis.com/get/share/), [social9](https://www.social9.com/)

Also, the ***[ngx-Sharebuttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sharebuttons)*** is the angular-ready plugin which supports your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Social9's [share](https://social9.com/#products) worked well for me. I have implemented it for [Square Deal Blog](https://blog.squaredeal.tax/). It also has the option to hide for Mobile devices. Placement can also be configured.